# deploying faye with capistrano 3 + command not found-

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3, faye

Well, I can't start faye with Capistrano. If I run the command directly on the server, it works.

This is my faye recipe:

```
set :faye_pid, "#{deploy_to}/shared/tmp/pids/faye.pid"
set :faye_config, "#{deploy_to}/current/private_pub.ru"

namespace :faye do
  task :start do
    on roles :all do

      execute "cd #{deploy_to}/current ; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production -D -P #{fetch(:faye_pid)}"
    end
  end

  task :stop do 
    on roles :all do
      execute "kill `cat #{fetch(:faye_pid)}` || true"
    end
  end
end

after  'deploy:publishing', 'faye:start'
before 'deploy:updating', 'faye:stop'
```

This is my configuration file to startup Faye:

```
# Run with: rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "private_pub"

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

PrivatePub.load_config(File.expand_path("../config/private_pub.yml", __FILE__), ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")
run PrivatePub.faye_app
```

And this is the SSHKIT error:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@255.255.255.255: cd /home/ubuntu/bhiz/current ; RAILS_ENV=production rackup1.6 private_pub.ru -s thin -E production -D -P /home/ubuntu/bhiz/shared/tmp/pids/faye.pid exit status: 127
cd /home/ubuntu/bhiz/current ; RAILS_ENV=production rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production -D -P /home/ubuntu/bhiz/shared/tmp/pids/faye.pid stdout: bash: rackup: command not found
```

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is much of an answer, but the issue is that somewhere along the line, `rackup` is getting converted to `rackup1.6` before execution. You might want to add Pry and Pry-Byebug to your gemfile, stick `binding.pry` in front of the `execute` line, and step through the code to see where and why it changes.

Comment: I'm sorry. That was one of the logs I got after testing the command using a different binary of rackup. The current log shows the same error but without the 1.6 in front of it. I will try with pry and pry-byebug to check it out. Thanks!